# Issue with differentiation using sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to differentiate this equation using SymPy:
[image]

What I wanted to achieve is this result:
[image]

But when I type this code into to execute, it gives me this result:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```py
import sympy as sp

# declare symbols
t = sp.Symbol('t')

deriv = sp.diff((t*(sp.cos(t)))/(1-t)**2)

# Find the derivative
sp.simplify(deriv)
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the same result. Break the result you get on the "+" and you get the same thing
[image]

Looking for the "simplest" form is not a well-defined problem and `sympy` can't guess which form you are looking for. You can always call `sp.simplify` on both the result you get and the desired answer. `sympy` will derive the same expression for both. In your case

```
result = sp.simplify(deriv)
desired = sp.simplify((-2 * t * sp.cos(t))/(t - 1)**3 + (-t * sp.sin(t) + sp.cos(t))/(t - 1)**2)
# result == desired
```

Comment: but is there a more automated process from sympy instead of manually breaking it myself?

Comment: “Simplest” is not a well-defined term, sympy can’t know exactly what you want when you are calling `simplify`

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion on how to be sure that the desired result is the same as your result

Comment: I see. So it's either we hardcode the formula out for sympy to render the equation or we manually break the result. Thank You!